# When talking about `apply for` certain operators, `apply to` is more appropriate, is my understanding right?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, expressions

this [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html) says

> Some additional rules `apply for` certain operators (e.g., a string as a left argument to the ‘%’ operator). Extensions must define their own conversion behavior.

per [cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-chinese-traditional/apply), when expressing have a connection, `apply to` should be used. For example, "That part of the form is for UK citizens - it doesn't apply to you."

`apply for` is used to express the meaning of "to request something". For example, "applied for a new job".

So, the description in the doc should be `apply to` rather than `apply for`.

Is my understanding right?

Answer (score 1):

"Apply" has multiple definitions. Your example has nothing at all to do with "making an application", as in the sense of applying for a job. In this case, it means "*be applicable or relevant*".

The document is saying that the additional rules *are applicable to* certain operators.

You are correct that *apply to* is normally used in this context and not *for*. However, "apply" does not have to be followed by either "to" or "for", for example, a common disclaimer is "*terms and conditions apply*". You can also say "rules apply *in* certain circumstances".

Arguably, the document is saying that rules apply, not *to* the operators (which I understand to be programming commands that represent an action), but *for* them, when they are used. I'm not sure that one can be dogmatic about this example, especially as it appears to be an excerpt from a *technical* manual, where *jargon* often takes precedent over the normal rules of grammar.